# First menu name is overwritten in Electron js

Tags: javascript, electron

I am trying to write a simple menu with Electron js and I notice that the name of the first menu is different from what I code.

This is my main.js:

```
const electron = require('electron')
const url = require('url')
const path = require('path')

const {app, BrowserWindow, Menu} = electron;

let mainWindow;

const mainMenuTemplate = [
    {
        label:'File',
        submenu: [
            {
                label: 'Custom Undo',
                role: 'undo'
            },
         ]
    },
    {
        label:'View',
        submenu: [
            {
               role: 'reload'
            },
        ]
    }
];

// Build menu from template
const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(mainMenuTemplate);

// Insert 
Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);

// Listen
app.on('ready', function(){

    // main window
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600});

    // load html into
    mainWindow.loadURL(url.format ({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'mainWindow.html'),
        protocol: 'file:',
        slashes: true
     }))
})
```

And this is the view of the application; notice the first item is named `Electron` instead of `File`.
[image]

The second menu item `View` is just fine. Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On macOS, the first menu item in the application menu is always named like the application itself ([source](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/menu#main-menus-name)). You should probably allow the first menu item to be what is customary on macOS, and then follow with the File menu.

To do that, but to also work cross-platform, you can do something along these lines:

```
const { app, Menu } = require('electron')

const isMac = process.platform === 'darwin'

const mainMenuTemplate = [
    ...(isMac ? [{
        label: app.name,
        submenu: [
            { role: 'about' },
            { type: 'separator' },
            { role: 'services' },
            { type: 'separator' },
            { role: 'hide' },
            { role: 'hideOthers' },
            { role: 'unhide' },
            { type: 'separator' },
            { role: 'quit' }
        ]
    }] : []),
    {
        label:'File',
        submenu: [
            {
                label: 'Custom Undo',
                role: 'undo'
            },
         ]
    },
    {
        label:'View',
        submenu: [
            {
               role: 'reload'
            },
        ]
    }
];
```

<sup>Code adapted from [example code in Electron docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/menu#examples) and OP's code.</sup>

Depending on the OS, the menu will either consist of 3 top-level objects (macOS) or 2 (non-macOS).